# How do Crew Dragon's main parachutes deploy?

Tags: dragon-v2, parachute

As far as I can tell, there are two distinct "doors" on Crew Dragon that house parachute-related equipment. In the below picture, I've outlined the upper door in yellow and the lower one in green.

[image: Crew Dragon annotated]

From the limited videos I've watched, it appears the yellow door detaches first using three springs located where the three holes are in the image. The drogues then deploy using explosive charges.

What I can't figure out is what happens next. It's clear the green door deploys at the time of main chute deployment, however videos of Crew Dragon descending show the main chutes clearly anchored from the upper door. So where are the mains found, and how does the rest of chute deployment work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This 2014 post in the NASASpaceflight forums](https://forum.nasaspaceflight.com/index.php?PHPSESSID=lt6o8aq3kl6fjue5jc4pcrdud8&topic=33852.msg1150053#msg1150053) shows how it worked for the parachute test capsules.  We know that the system was changed some since then, but the most basic things (i.e. what goes where) are likely to be the same.

In that post's pictures, you can clearly see that the drogues are fired from the top hatch (yellow in your picture) and lines run down around the crew hatch to the mains underneath the green door.

[Photos of the recovered Demo-2 capsule](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/spacex-crew-dragon-endeavour-lifted-aboard-recovery-ship) indicate that the same setup is likely still in place; see the cutouts around the crew hatch.

[[image: Recovered Demo-2 capsule]
NASA/Bill Ingalls](https://www.nasa.gov/image-feature/spacex-crew-dragon-endeavour-lifted-aboard-recovery-ship)

Comment: it's late and I'm likely not going to be able to give this answer the love it needs to be a good one, but I think it's a good enough start for a community wiki.